# Is there a notation for incomplete quotient

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation

If $n, m > 0$ are integers and $m \nmid n,$ how to denote the incomplete quotient this division?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use $\lfloor n/m \rfloor$

Comment: Ah thank you so much.

Comment: that's true for positive result of n/m. For negative result, ⌈n/m⌉

Answer (score 0):

Possible through "floor" and "ceiling" functions (rounding down and rounding up)

```
⌊n/m⌋, if n/m > 0
⌈n/m⌉, if n/m < 0
```

second line needed because ⌊⌋ rounds argument value to integer value which is *less* than argument.

Or

```
⌊|n/m|⌋ ( sgn n/m )
```

Sometimes brakets [] or reverse brackets ][ used to designate integer pert.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions#Notation